# SMS text messages on Huawei p smart 2017

Tags: backup, sms, data-recovery, huawei, sqlite

How do I recover SMS that have been deleted from my phone? I have phone of brand Huawei p smart 2017.

Comment: create backup with HiSuite and examine database for deleted entries https://www.staff.hs-mittweida.de/~pawlaszc/fqlite

Comment: Welcome to an international Q&A site, Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Just for info that this site has [English-only policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/241919). Using simple English is okay, and the community can improve it later if it's already in English.